# OpenCV Rect x and y represent (column,row) or (row,column)

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, rect

I want to replace a rectangular part of an image (Mat) with 0 values. My image has 1000 number of rows and 1500 number of columns. I want to mask a patch having width 150 and height 100 at (890,1340). For this, I am using following code snippet:

```
cv::Rect patch;
patch.y = 890;
patch.x = 1340;
patch.height = 100;
patch.width = 150;
image(patch) = 0;
```

But I am getting following error:

OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in cv::arithm_op, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp, line 659

I have changed x and y coordinates of Rect patch but still getting same error. I searched on Internet but I am still confused about Rect parameters.

Whether Rect x,y represent (column,row) or (row,column)?

Comment: x is column and y is row.... you should show how image was created to have an idea of what the error is about

Comment: image(patch) .setTo(cv::Scalar(0));

Comment: thank you @Miki, it worked using mentioned command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Rect` x represent columns and y represent rows. This means that image.at(i,j) is using (i,j) as (row,column) but Rect(x,y) is using (x,y) as (column,row).